# Filling in a list until a multiple of a number

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I am trying to round a lists length upwards to a multiple of three, using empty strings(`''`). For example:

`['a','b']` >>> `['a','b','']`

`['a','b','c']` >>> `['a','b','c']`

`['a','b','c','d']` >>> `['a','b','c','d','','']`

how would I go about doing this without an if statement? Would I use modulo to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just compute number of strings to add and perform the addition in-place:

```
l = ['a','b','c','d']

l += ['']*((3-len(l))%3)

print(l)
```

result:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', '', '']
```

The performance is the best, specially with numbers higher than 3 for the multiple.

Answer (score 4):

This is the fastest and (IMO) most readable way to do it:

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

while len(l) % 3 != 0:
    l.append('')
```

[Performance test using `timeit`](https://gist.github.com/cetanu/412796176c9537ad9a12fc6fe81d64f0)

Comment: I like this answer, but I feel like the concise answer given by `Jean-François Fabre` is deserving of the acceptance mark.

Comment: very good if the number is not too high, which is the case here. Good.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = [
    ['a','b'],
    ['a','b','c'],
    ['a','b','c','d'],
]

for row in data:
    result = row + ([''] * (-len(row) % 3))
    print(row, '>>>', result)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
def fillmultiple(lst):
    ll = len(lst) #calculate the length of the list
    toadd = (3-ll)%3 #calculate how much additional elements to add
    return lst+['']*toadd #return the list with the elements added
```

The code simply uses modulo calculation (`%3`) to calculate how much the length is off from the next multiple of three.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by appending extra empty strings.

```
l=['a','b','b','c']

while (3-len(l))%3: l.append('')
```

That's it!